# Keychain viewers - what does DPFMate do?

Tags: image, path

Got this Digital Keychain Photo viewer thingy. Comes with DPFMate which does not run under Windows 10. Does anyone know where DPFMate places the images on the keychain, so I could possibly write my own program to do the move?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i know this thread dates back to April but i have a device that uses DPFmate and it was packaged with it in memory. the software came with a windows and a mac version. fortunately most of the code is literally available in an uncompiled form in the mac app package. i have included everything from that package in a mediafire link. https://www.mediafire.com/file/ebyxepk013k18pd/Resources.rar

from what i gathered it loads a virtual drive from the machine using a SCSI connection driver of some sorts. i hope you can make sens of it more than me since i am not familiar with the programming language used.

Comment: Accepted since it's the only answer here, and is somewhat reasonable. Also, weirdly enough, on latest win10, it started to work..